# Accents insensitive search in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database named: `Movies` whit colation `utf8_spanish_ci`

inside is the table `peliculas` whit collation `utf8_spanish2_ci`

inside the field `nombre` whit collation `utf8_spanish2_ci`too.

The data in field name whit accents saves like this:

```
La CacerÃ­a    // La cacería
El cÃ­rculo    // El círculo
```

actually I Use the query: `SELECT * FROM peliculas WHERE nombre like '%$string%'` but if I search without accent does not yield any results.

So

The query search and results should be:

```
|query    | Result |
|------------------|
|circulo  | cÃ­rculo|
|caceria  | CacerÃ­a|
 ------------------
```

Any Idea is welcome

Comment: Do you want this to happen for all vowels (a,e,i,o,u) or just for i?

Comment: Why _would_ you store accents like that? If the string is `"El círculo"`, _store_ `"El círculo"`, and you it would just work (provided you remembered to do a `SET NAMES utf8;` or similar). As the data is now... you're only making it difficult for yourself.

Comment: The better way is to use UTF-8 and avoid additional work when querying.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos is for all vowels.

Comment: @josesanchez Then try Brad Christie's answer. I believe it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *believe* you need to specify [`COLLATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) as part of the SQL statement.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    peliculas
WHERE   nombre LIKE '%circulo%' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

[example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5afd72/1/0) which returns:

```
+-----+------------+
| ID  | NOMBRE     |
+-----+------------+
| 2   | El círculo |
+-----+------------+
```

*(Not I didn't use `í` within the query, but still was able to return `El círculo`)*

I should note, if you're database encoding isn't setup and you're actually storing every "accent" as `Ã` you're going to have a lot more problems. This only works on the basis that the database itself has the *original unreplaced value*.

Alternatively, a full-text search would probably do the trick.

p.s. Look in to using [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) and stop placing `$var` in a query.